# Find inverse Fourier transform of Lorentzian using complex integration

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, residue-calculus, complex-integration

I am trying to prove the inverse Fourier transform relation of a Lorentzian

$$F(\omega) = \dfrac{2b}{(\omega-a)^2+b^2} = \dfrac{1}{b+i(\omega-a)}+\dfrac{1}{b-i(\omega-a)}$$

using the relation

$$f(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{d\omega}{2\pi}e^{-i\omega t} F(\omega)$$

with the method of residues. (From Wikipedia, the solution should be $f(t)=e^{-b|t|-iat}$)

The first term in $F(\omega)$ has a pole at $\omega=a+ib$ so the semicircle contour goes anticlockwise on the upper half of the complex plane. The second term has a pole at $\omega=a-ib$ so the semicircle contour goes clockwise on the lower half of the complex plane. Then calculating the residues:

$2\pi i \sum$ (residues in upper half of plane) - $2\pi i \sum$ (residues in lower half of plane)

we get

$$2\pi i \left( \dfrac{e^{-i(a+ib)t}}{b-i(a+ib-a)} \right) - 2\pi i \left( \dfrac{e^{-i(a-ib)t}}{b+i(a-ib-a)} \right)$$

and the solution is

$$f(t) = 2b \dfrac{e^{-iat}}{2b} (e^{bt}-e^{-bt})$$

What is the justification for letting $e^{bt}-e^{-bt} \to e^{-b|t|}$? Is it related to how I draw the contours on the complex plane?

Comment: I got $e^{b|t|-iat}$...

Comment: There seems to be an error since the inverse Fourier transform has a positive sign in the exponential and in the question there is a negative sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(z)$ be your integrand.

This integral has to be evaluated case-by-case:

**For $t>0$:**

$e^{-iwt}$ converges to zero at infinity on the lower half plane.

Thus, we take an infinitely large semi-circle contour on the lower half plane, centered at origin.

By residue theorem, $$\underbrace{\int_{\text{arc}}f(z)dz}_{\to0}-\int^\infty_{-\infty}f(z)dz=2\pi i\text{Res}_{z=a-bi}f(z)\overbrace {=}^{\text{as you calculated}}e^{-bt-iat}$$

Therefore, $$\color{blue}{\int^\infty_{-\infty}f(z)dz=e^{-bt-iat}}$$

**For $t<0$:**

Now take an infinitely large semicircle on the upper half plane as contour, centered at zero.

$$\underbrace{\int_{\text{arc}}f(z)dz}_{\to0}+\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(z)dz=2\pi i\text{Res}_{z=a+bi}f(z)=e^{bt-iat}$$

Therefore, $$\color{blue}{\int^\infty_{-\infty}f(z)dz=e^{bt-iat}}$$

**Gluing two cases together:**

$$\color{red}{\frac1\pi\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{be^{-ixt}}{(x-a)^2+b^2}dx=e^{-b|t|-iat}}$$

Comment: Ok, but when I use Mathematica's `InverseFourierTransform` function, I get the solution $e^{-iat}(e^{bt}\theta(-t)+e^{-bt}\theta(t))$ which is the same as $e^{-iat}(e^{-b|t|})$. Maybe I misunderstand this, but I subtract the residue because: when the contour goes anticlockwise we add the residue, when it's clockwise we need a minus sign. Is that correct?

Comment: @MedullaOblongata The procedures are: because $$\oint=\sum\text{included residue}$$ 1. decompose the $\oint$ into arc integral and straight line integral 2. prove arc integral vanish, thus LHS becomes your desired integral 3. evaluate included residues. Residues would not gain a negative sign because of the orientation of contour. The negative sign will appear naturally on the LHS and you don’t have to care much.

Comment: @MedullaOblongata Moreover, the integral you presented in your question is the Fourier transform(not inverse). As soon as you correct it, I will correct my answer too.

Comment: great thanks. FYI there is actually more than one way to define a Fourier transform. I know that you're referring to the definition in Wikipedia, but the definition in my question often appears in field theory textbooks. This is the form I'm using. I also don't understand why your solution and the Mathematica result don't agree...

Comment: @MedullaOblongata But maybe Mathematica agrees with Wikipedia but not your textbook...

Comment: @MedullaOblongata Btw I like your name:)

Comment: Thanks :) Mathematica's `InverseFourierTransform` gives you options where you can specify what form of the FT you want to calculate. I've ensured that it performs the same FT as in the textbook, https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFourierTransform.html

Comment: @MedullaOblongata Oh no! I found my mistake! I sincerely apologize, and would correct my answer now.